# Host ASPNET pages in Windows Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

There's a section of a web site I maintain that has many thousands of pages that are fairly static.  They are ASPX pages, but they have no code-behind.  They DO have references to a master page and they have `<asp:Content>` tags so they do need server-side processing.

It is hosted in Azure, but the site takes forever to build and update due to the number of pages. It seems like it should be possible to upload all these pages to blob storage and reference them from there.  They change relatively rarely.

I guess I could just change this from a relative URL to a fully explicit URL, right?

```
<%@ Page Title="WhateverPage" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MyMasterPage.master" %>
```

Then anywhere else in the site that there's a link to the page, link to the page's URL in blob storage.

That seem doable or are there snags I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

Moving static content to blob storage works great. Just be sure to place your static content in public containers. And... while you're at it, you should consider moving all static images, stylesheets, etc. to blobs as well.

The big task will be going through all your content, modifying  and other tags in those static pages, to point to blob storage explicitly, if needed (as maybe you store your images in a different storage account).

You'll gain a few benefits as well:

- Smaller deployment package (as you alluded to already)
- Ability to update a single page or image without a redeployment, just buy uploading a new item to blob storage
- Less demand on IIS and your compute instances

One caveat, though: You can't have a "default" page. That is, if you just point to `http://mywebsiteinblobstorage.com`, you can't specify a default object (say, default.html).

Comment: It definitely will be a task, but I may go this route.  There's one thing still bothering me though.  In the reference to master page I would have to put an explicit URL.  I deploy to one of three different web roles.  We have a test site and a production site.  The test site has one web role, and the production site has one role for staging and one role for the live site.  So I can't hard code a URL in there.

Comment: You can't just redirect the http request to a new URL as there is no ASPNET web server responding to those requests.  You would have to read the file content from blob yourself I believe? Custom HTTP module?

Comment: Ok, well here's my solution: http://jvshangout.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/virtualpathprovider-for-windows-azure-hosting-aspx-web-pages-in-blob-storage/